# How to install chandelier fixture in ceiling hole that is too big?

Tags: lighting, drywall, ceiling, hole

I am trying to replace my dining room chandelier, and after removing the old fixture one, I realized that the new fixture is too big for the size of the hole. That means, I don't have space to put the anchors to hold the fixture over the hole. The hole is too big.

[image: Hole too big to allow screwing fixture into drywall]

What is a proper solution so I can hold the fixture securely in this hole? The chandelier is lightweight, 2.5 pounds.

Comment: You don't hang a chandelier from drywall, unless you enjoy reenacting those scenes in movies where one comes crashing down..

Comment: It is lightweight. 2.5 pounds. https://a.co/d/hd89Wfg - and I will be putting anchors.

Comment: Where in the world are you located that you have two white wires and a bare ground? Or is one of those wires actually black but was (not so) conveniently painted by a lazy painter who couldn't work around the box?

Comment: The latter. They were painted unfortunately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The metal bracket in the picture is meant to be secured with screws into those 2 holes you see facing downward in the electric box. Usually those are 8-32 pitch machine screws.

Those slots in the bracket are so it can fit either a 3 1/2" or 4" round box.

Comment: Oh, I see! That makes sense. I thought I had to screw those into the drywall. I guess with long enough screws, this will be solved. Thanks!

Comment: @Nobita since the bracket is wider than the hole in the ceiling use washers (and long enough screws) to pad around the screws so the bracket doesn't get bent when you tighten the mounting screws down. I'd guess that the light will mount to this bracket and any bend means that the light won't fit properly.